# Error in my textbook?

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus

Given

[image]

Shouldn't the second line (third equation)'s denominator be negative?

i.e. $-\sqrt(x^2/x^2)$

like this:

[image]

Comment: For $x$ of interest, $x < 0$, so $-1/x > 0$.  The denominator is a product of two positive terms.  So it is positive.

Comment: I think there _is_ an error in your textbook: what I call a "tactical" error. They solved the limit correctly, but they made it far more complicated than it needed to be while doing so. The method @Harish Chandra Rajpoot showed you is better. But in any case you have two correct answers showing why the book's solution actually works.

Comment: @DavidK I am supremely confused now

Comment: Of course you're confused, and I think the book is primarily to blame for that, because they showed you a solution that _looks wrong_ even though it actually is correct.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No: you have $\frac{\sqrt{x^2}}{-x} = \frac{\sqrt{x^2}}{\sqrt{x^2}} = \sqrt{\frac{x^2}{x^2}}$ since $x$ is negative. You can check the signs: first LHS is negative, last RHS is still negative: all is fine.

Comment: I don't understand. Isn't the priority for the $-$ to go in front of the $\sqrt(x^2)$? and then whatever is in the denominator gets handled after?

Comment: You always have $\sqrt{x^2}=\lvert x\rvert$. So for $x < 0$, $\sqrt{x^2}=\lvert x\rvert=-x$.

Comment: The square root is always the POSITIVE square root (convention), so if $x$ is negative , we have $\sqrt{x^2}=-x$ because $-x$ is positive, when $x$ is negative.

Comment: I'm still not following... I understand that $\sqrt(x^2) = |x| = -x = x$. And I understand that powering it to $x^2$ makes it positive. But doesn't the operation of powering $x$ happen after the sign gets transferred to the $\sqrt()$? In my mind the $-$ is not even on the $x$, it is on the 1...

Comment: Do you agree that x = -|x| when x is negative?

Comment: I see $\frac{-\sqrt{x^2}}{x}$

Comment: @ClementC. Yes I do

Comment: And do you agree that $\sqrt{x^2} = \lvert x\rvert$ for any $x$? Using the two, you get that, for $x<0$, $x = -\sqrt{x^2}$.

Comment: @ClementC. Yes I agree

Comment: So then, you have (for the numerator) $(x+1)\cdot \frac{-1}{x} = -1-\frac{1}{x}$ as written; and, the key point, for the denominator you get $\sqrt{x^2}\cdot  \frac{-1}{x} = \sqrt{x^2}\cdot  \frac{1}{-x} = \sqrt{x^2}\cdot  \frac{1}{\sqrt{x^2}} = \frac{\sqrt{x^2}}{\sqrt{x^2}}=\sqrt{\frac{x^2}{x^2}}$. In case something in this last chain of equalities bothers you, which one is it?

Comment: @ClementC. It's the third one. I understand how that makes sense, but doesn't it also make sense to leave the $-$ on the $1$, and then move it down when the $x$ becomes $\sqrt{x^2}$?

Comment: @ClementC see the question edit

Comment: The issue is the same: looking at what you have written in your edit (note that you can ignore the numerator for the sake of the discussion, everything is fine "up there"), what you want to do is write $$-\frac{\sqrt{x^2}}{x} = -\sqrt{\frac{x^2}{x^2}}$$ but this is **false**: indeed, the RHS is now negative, while the LHS is positive (try with $x=-1$ to see). The key here is that $-\frac{1}{x} = \frac{1}{\sqrt{x^2}}$ for $x<0$, **not** $-\frac{1}{x} = - \frac{1}{\sqrt{x^2}}$.

Comment: @ClementC sorry I've been trying really hard to understand this for the past 30 minutes but I just got even more confused

Comment: Take $x=-2$. Then $x^2 =4$, and $\sqrt{x^2} = 2 = -x$. So you have $-\frac{\sqrt{x^2}}{x} = -\frac{4}{-2} = \frac{4}{2} = \frac{\sqrt{x^2}}{\sqrt{x^2}}$. The point is, **factoring $x$ as $\sqrt{x^2}$ only works for $x\geq 0$**: for $x<0$, you get $x = -\sqrt{x^2}$ instead.

Comment: If $$\sqrt{\frac{x^2}{x^2}}$$ does not become negative after being factored from $\frac{-1}{x^2}$, then when is it ever negative?

Comment: I do not understand. By definition, $\sqrt{a}$ is **never** negative, for any $a\geq 0$. $\sqrt{}$ is a function from $[0,\infty)$ to $[0,\infty)$. When $x$ is negative, $\sqrt{x^2}$ is still positive: that's why then $\sqrt{x^2}=-x$ (both sides are now positive).

Comment: Still kinda confused so I'll go read up. Thanks a lot for your time nonetheless @ClementC

Comment: You're welcome -- and I hope the confusion will clear up. For what it's worth, as pointed out in a comment above by @David K, the way your book writes the proof is very prone to confusion, and it's no wonder it causes some.

Answer (score 2):

No, for negative $x$ we have $\sqrt{\frac{1}{x^2}}=-\frac{1}{x}$

Answer (score 0):

When in doubt, use the substitution $t=-x$, so your limit becomes
$$
\lim_{t\to\infty}\frac{-t+1}{\sqrt{t^2}}=
\lim_{t\to\infty}\frac{1-t}{t}=
\lim_{t\to\infty}\left(\frac{1}{t}-1\right)
$$

About your doubt, note that for $x<0$ (which you can assume to begin with), you have $\sqrt{x^2}=-x$, so
$$
\sqrt{x^2}\cdot\left(-\frac{1}{x}\right)=
\sqrt{x^2}\cdot\left(\frac{1}{-x}\right)=
\sqrt{x^2}\frac{1}{\sqrt{x^2}}=\sqrt{x^2\cdot\frac{1}{x^2}}
$$

Comment: I don't understand why the $-$ doesn't just go to the left! before $\sqrt{x^2}$

Comment: @EricJohnson It's “eaten” by $-x=\sqrt{x^2}$.